# How to find selected rows of gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
            'id'           => 'employee-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [

                          'first_name',
            ],
        ]); ?>
```

How to find the selected rows of gridview in ajax

Comment: Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53777-gridview-get-selected-colum/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need

```
$('#employee-grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

Comment: This is returning data-key what if I want vlaue of checkbox